# How to use Same Object Name in <jsp:useBean >

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

am getting duplicate variable error while compilation of JSP .Please help me.Here scope(session and request) of the Attribute is different then why I couldn't use this ?
It expects id must be different but in different scope also why it expects ?

```
HttpSession hs = request.getSession();
hs.setAttribute("GrandParents",new GrandParents());

request.setAttribute("GrandParents",new GrandParents());

 <jsp:useBean id="GrandParents" type="test.bean.GrandParents" class="test.bean.GrandParents" scope="request"/>
     Name in JSP Request tag is: <jsp:getProperty name="GrandParents" property="name" />

<jsp:useBean  id ="GrandParents" type="test.bean.GrandParents" class="test.bean.GrandParents" scope="session"/>
 Name in JSP Request tag is: <jsp:getProperty name="GrandParentss" property="name" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is used to specify the name of the variable used to refere to the bean. So the above code is equivalent to

```
GrandParents GrandParents = (GrandParents) request.getAttribute("GrandParents");
GrandParents GrandParents = (GrandParents) session.getAttribute("GrandParents");
```

And this is invalid, because it defines two variables with the same name.

jsp:useBean shouldn't be used for years anyway. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL, and simply do

```
Name in JSP Request is: ${requestScope.GrandParents.name}
Name in JSP Session is: ${sessionScope.GrandParents.name}
```

Also, the convention is to name attributes the same way as Java local variables: starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: sorry for delay its ok with JSTL am learning , Could you help me how to achieve this using the <jsp:tags..........> as I mentioned. ?